# Find cells in excel which have a format other than General like Custom

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2003

In my excel workbook most of the cells have General as number format. However few cells have custom formatting set to them. With excel 2003 format (.xls), sometimes when huge amount of formatted data is saved then excel is ripping apart the formatting applied which is resulting in data loss with number formatted cells. So, I am looking for an option to identify such cells in the workbook which have a number format other than General, so that I can remove the custom formatting applied to them.

I am new to excel formulas / macro programming, however any suggestions in that direction would be helpful as well. The inbuilt find function was not helpful at all.

[image: Number Format in Excel]

Comment: Select all cells and choose General format not good?

Comment: Doing so will remove the custom format already applied to that cell which results in data loss.

Comment: Then i don't understand this `which have a number format other than General, so that I can remove the custom formatting applied to them.` Additionally formatting in rare cases changes the content of the cell.

Comment: As shown in picture, I can take a number and suffix them with either mm or in or lbm by applying custom format. My workbook has lot of such  cells with custom format. My requirement is to figure out those cells so that i can manually correct them.

Comment: Please, try the code I posted and send some feedback. It places the sheet used range in an array (faster to iterate and process part of the query) and only for numeric values in cel it checks `NumberFormat`. It not `General` it places it in a `Union` range, to be highlighted by coloring its cells interior, **at once**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, try the next function able to create a `Union` range of the cells having numeric value and not being formatted as `General`. It should be fast enough, using an array and the above mentioned `Union` range, to be formatted at once, at the end:

```
Function findNoGeneralFormat(w As Worksheet) As Range
  Dim URng As Range, arr, Ur As Range, i As Long, j As Long
  
  Set URng = w.UsedRange
  URng.Interior.Color = xlNone 'clear the previously colored cells
                               'comment this line if this is not convenient (having already highlighted cells needed to remain colored)
  arr = URng.Value2
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        If IsNumeric(arr(i, j)) Then
            If URng.cells(i, j).NumberFormat <> "General" Then
                addToRange Ur, URng.cells(i, j)
            End If
        End If
    Next j
  Next i
  If Not Ur Is Nothing Then Set findNoGeneralFormat = Ur
End Function
```

The necessary sub to create the `Union` range:

```
Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

It can be used in the next way:

```
Sub testfindNoGeneralFormat()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, noGenFormat As Range
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   
   Set noGenFormat = findNoGeneralFormat(ws)
   If Not noGenFormat Is Nothing Then noGenFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

The above code will also color `Date` formatted cells, if the case. It can be adapted to also skip them, if necessary.

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: This worked for me. The crux was `If URng.cells(i, j).NumberFormat <> "General" Then`. I also customized it a bit to write to text file to review it from one place.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in a module in VBA and start.

Tools -> Macro -> Visual Basic

```
Sub coloring()

For Each a In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If a.NumberFormat <> "General" Then
 a.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 232, 124)
End If
Next a

End Sub
```

It will color all cells which is not General formatted.